# Ошибка при резервном копировании

Tags: администрирование, резервное-копирование, hdd, клонирование

Попытаюсь  сделать образ hdd на ноутбуке через Acronis Image 2017, загруженого через Windows 8 PE с помощью dvd диска.
Место куда записать образ это диск на 4 тб (свободно 2,7 тб) архивированная память 32 гб. подсоедененный к удаленному пк, сделал шару на удаленный доступ к этому диску и по сети заливаю образ. В процессе вижу что появляется на 4 тб диске имя ноутбука и постепенно увеличение его размера.
Но, в процессе выдает ошибку,как следствие исчезает образ с 4 тб диска тоже.
Разобрать ноутбук, что бы изъять hdd мне не дадут.
Всунул новый 4 тб диск. Также история.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто сталкивался, как решить проблему?

Comment: Попробуй через Clonezilla livecd. Она менее навороченная (хотя хзхз) и памяти она жрёт максимум пол гига.

Comment: Там лецензия на винду и софт, через acronis я уверен что не слетит.

Comment: Я как пользователь Клонзиллы с 2010-го - тоже уверен, но не слетят. Тем более лицензии хранятся внутри диска C:\, а не где-то в магических областях. А если это цифровая лицензия или kms, то вообще похрен даже если умрёт винт.

Comment: При клонировании диска у через Acronis по слетали лицензии на винде)
Классно было время, бах и оборудование стало)

Comment: Ну а через Клонзиллу не слетали. Акронис умеет лазить в реестр, если память не изменяет. Так что вполне возможно.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему следующим образом. Если раньше я делал бэкап через Windows PE. НО есть программа  Acronis True Image 2016, он устанавливается и делает бэкап в рантайме, машину не грузил,тормозов не было, делал на удаленный сервер. Развернул и работает все отлично)